# Create charts in Vaadin application without Vaadin Charts?

Tags: java, web, charts, vaadin, vaadin7

There is a free alternative to Vaadin Charts to be used in a "Vaadin application"?

I would not spend money for the project that I am developing.

- Vaadin: 7.4
- Apache Tomcat V8
- JDK 1.8

Comment: I've managed to create charts using Charts.js http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: It's not a simple solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found dCharts widget, but I have no idea how to use.

I asked here: [How use dCharts Widget in a Vaadin project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265243/how-use-dcharts-widget-in-a-vaadin-project)