# How use dCharts Widget in a Vaadin project?

Tags: java, web, charts, vaadin, vaadin7

I was looking for a 'free alternative to Vaadin Charts and found DCharts Widget, but I can not find guides or complete documentation to' use.
Does anyone know how to import and use this widget?
The guides to get started?

- Vaadin: 7.4
- Apache Tomcat V8
- JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

To use dCharts i have execute this step:

1. Download .jar or copy dependency for maven/ivy from: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dcharts-widget
2. Follow the instructions in [this official page](http://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons/) based on your installation method. (I have choose to download .jar and compile it with [Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse](https://vaadin.com/eclipse))

Small exemple of code:

```
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries()
      .add(1, 5, 8, 2, 3);

     SeriesDefaults seriesDefaults = new SeriesDefaults()
      .setRenderer(SeriesRenderers.BAR);

     Axes axes = new Axes()
     .addAxis(
             new XYaxis().setRenderer(AxisRenderers.CATEGORY)
             .setTicks(new Ticks()
                     .add("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")));

     Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter()
     .setShow(false);

     Options options = new Options()
      .setSeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults)
      .setAxes(axes)
      .setHighlighter(highlighter);

     DCharts chart = new DCharts()
      .setDataSeries(dataSeries)
      .setOptions(options)
      .show();
layout.addComponent(chart);
```